# Function returning nothing

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am creating a desktop application with tkinter that utilizes OpenCV for some tasks later on. I am trying to create a function that reads a file path and returns that path as a string. It returns `<function UploadAction at 0x00000246B6A42E50>` and I have a `print()` to verify if `askopenfilename` is printing the path correctly and it is. So what am I overlooking/not looking at here? Here's the code:

```
def UploadAction():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    print(file)
    return file

mystr= UploadAction
img= cv.imread('{}'.format(mystr)) 

def Image(event=None):
    #cv.imshow('img', img)
    #cv.waitKey(0)
    #cv.destroyAllWindows()
    print(mystr)
    print(UploadAction)
```

The functions are called through buttons, they work fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you want to implement a callback

Comment: looks like you need to learn more about tkinter. your code contains no actual use of it, yet you expect things to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You need Parenthesis`()`, or else the function won't be called -

```
mystr= UploadAction()
```

Also, this - `img= cv.imread('{}'.format(mystr))` can be simplified -

```
img= cv.imread(mystr)
```

Comment: I don't want to call the function, I want to store the returned value which is a string so I can copy that string into the `imread` function. The functions are called through buttons in my app.

Comment: If you don't call it, how are you gonna get the returned value? Also, please tell me what happens if you run my code?

Comment: `img= cv.imread('mystr')` should be `img= cv.imread(mystr)` instead.

Comment: @acw1668, Oh yeah. Sorry, my bad. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need parenthesis in order to call "UploadAction".

If you don't put parenthesis, you will store a pointer to the function rather than executing UploadAction and setting the return value into mystr.

```
mystr = UploadAction()
```